# Usage of Reselect with observables in Angular 6+ app

Tags: angular, redux, observable, reselect

I am working on an Angular 6 app with redux in the mix.

Currently, all of my selectors are one of the two shapes:

```
this.store.select<ActiveProject>(['projectList', 'map', this.projectId])
```

or

```
@select(['parameterList', 'parameters']) 
parameters$: Observable<Parameter[]>
```

Both of these return Observable, which is awesome, as it nicely follows the conventions of Angular. And Angular has all the bells and whistles to work with them.

I started looking into Reselect library (https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). This library simplifies the selectors a lot (in addition to a bunch of other benefits). However, the selectors in reselect do not return Observable (if I understand correctly).

Does it mean that if I want to use reselect with my app, I basically cannot use Observables anymore?

Or am I missing something?